# How do I get my current ruby program to loop through three input options and display if the same option has been used twice?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am attempting to get my current program to give the user three different input options and notify the user if they have attempted to use the same input option twice.
My current code:

```
prompt = "Do you want to use the Subscription coupon[1] the one-time pay-per-use 
coupon[2] or the gift purchase coupon[3]: "
print prompt
code = gets.chomp
code = code.to_i
history = []

loop do
    if code == 1
            puts "Subscription coupon used"
            print prompt
            code = gets.chomp
    elsif code == 2
            puts "One-time pay-per-use coupon used"
            print prompt
            code = gets.chomp
    elsif code == 3
            puts "Gift purchase coupon used"
            print prompt
            code = gets.chomp
    else history.include? code
            puts "Code already input"
            print prompt
            code = gets.chomp
    end
end
```

It is allowing me to input as many times as I want, but no matter what the second input is it prints the code already input text.

How do I fix the code to get it to run in the intended way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the history check to the beginning of your loop, and actually populate the history.
Here's one of many ways to accomplish that:

```
loop do
  if history.include?(code)
    puts 'Code already input'
    print prompt
    code = gets.chomp.to_i
    next # Stop processing this iteration of the loop immediately, and skip to the next iteration.
  else
    history << code
  end

  if code == 1
    puts 'Subscription coupon used'
  elsif code == 2
    puts 'One-time pay-per-use coupon used'
  elsif code == 3
    puts 'Gift purchase coupon used'
  else
    puts 'Invalid entry.'  
  end

  print prompt
  code = gets.chomp.to_i
end
```

Comment: Thank you, your answer really helped me out. When running the code as you have shown the first input  is always the correct name, but then any other button pressed after that initial button is the puts prompt from 'else code == 3' until that button is pressed a second time. Is there anyway to fix this?

Comment: @colewalk there are a few issues here: 1. `else code == 3` is not a conditional branch probably change to `elsif`; 2. Correcting #1 means we should have an `else` branch for invalid entries; 3. `code` will never be equal to `1`, `2`, or `3` (Integer) because `gets.chomp` returns a `String`. (missing `to_i` or compare code with `"1"`, `"2"`, `"3"`)

Comment: @engineersmnky changing every case of gets.chomp to gets.chomp.to_i and adding a true else statement, I still get the issue of any number I input the first time it gives the correct input, the second input will say already input, but if you switch from say 1 to 2 it still uses the put statement from code == 1                                                                  Edit to add: Infact any initial input gives the puts statement from code ==1

Comment: @engineersmnky nevermind. I had somehow changed all of the if statement == to single =. This fixed it. Thank you!

Comment: Sorry for the issues, I wrote this without a way to evaluate/test it. I've added the proposed fixes to my answer as they make sense to me. Thank you @engineersmnky for catching those.

Answer (score 1):

You might consider writing that as follows. Note that I've added a bit.

```
valid_entries = ["1", "2", "3", "4"]
answers = []

loop do
  puts  "\nDo you want to use the"
  puts  "  Subscription coupon (1)"
  puts  "  One-time pay-per-use coupon (2) or"
  puts  "  Gift purchase coupon (3)?"
  puts  "Enter (4) if you are finished"
  print "Your selection: "

  entry = gets.chomp

  unless valid_entries.include?(entry)
    puts "'#{entry}'is not a valid entry, you dummy. Try again."
    next
  end

  if answers.include?(entry)
    puts "You've already made that selection. Try again."
    next
  else
    answers << entry
  end

  break if entry == "4"

  puts case(entry)
    when '1' then "Subscription coupon used"
    when '2' then "One-time pay-per-use coupon used"
    when '3' then "Gift purchase coupon used"
  end
end
```

---

Here is a possible conversation.

```
Do you want to use the
  Subscription coupon (1)
  One-time pay-per-use coupon (2) or
  Gift purchase coupon (3)?
Enter (4) if you are finished
Your selection: 1
Subscription coupon used
```

```
Do you want to use the
  Subscription coupon (1)
  One-time pay-per-use coupon (2) or
  Gift purchase coupon (3)?
Enter (4) if you are finished
Your selection: 2
One-time pay-per-use coupon used
```

```
Do you want to use the
  Subscription coupon (1)
  One-time pay-per-use coupon (2) or
  Gift purchase coupon (3)?
Enter (4) if you are finished
Your selection: 1
You've already made that selection. Try again.
```

```
Do you want to use the
  Subscription coupon (1)
  One-time pay-per-use coupon (2) or
  Gift purchase coupon (3)?
Enter (4) if you are finished
Your selection: %
'%'is not a valid entry, you dummy. Try again.
```

```
Do you want to use the
  Subscription coupon (1)
  One-time pay-per-use coupon (2) or
  Gift purchase coupon (3)?
Enter (4) if you are finished
Your selection: 4
```

---

As an alternative to

```
puts case(entry)
  when '1' then "Subscription coupon used"
  when '2' then "One-time pay-per-use coupon used"
  when '3' then "Gift purchase coupon used"
end
```

you could write

```
puts MESSAGES[entry]
```

after having defined the constant

```
MESSAGES = { '1'=>"Subscription coupon used",
             '2'=>"One-time pay-per-use coupon used"
             '3'=>"Gift purchase coupon used" }
```

Comment: Hahaha +1 for "...you dummy..." 